# Explain Code First CRUD auto-generated SQL for Identity column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Code-first auto generates an insert procedure code as below for a table that has `ProductID` as primary key (identity column).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertProducts]
    @ProductName [nvarchar](max),
    @Date [datetime],
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.ProductsTable([ProductName], [Date])
    VALUES (@ProductName, @Date)

    -- identity stuff starts here
    DECLARE @ProductID int

    SELECT @ProductID = [ProductID]
    FROM dbo.FIT_StorageLocations
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ProductID] = scope_identity()

    SELECT t0.[ProductID]
    FROM dbo.ProductsTable AS t0
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[ProductID] = @ProductID
END
GO
```

Could you please explain the code that handles the identity column? Also, if an insert procedure is to be manually written from scratch, would it be handled differently?

If for example I would remove this auto generated code, I would encounter one of the following errors:

> Procedure ....expects parameter '@ProductID', which was not supplied
>
> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

In the app, this is how I call the procedure which works fine until I try to mess with the code first auto generated SQL:

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    var record = new ProductObj()
              {
                ProductName= this.ProductName,
                Date = DateTime.UtcNow
              };
    db.ProductDbSet.Add(record);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are two things to be explained here.

### Why a `SELECT` statement when I insert stuff?

Let's first see what a regular insert by Entity Framework looks like. By "regular" I mean an insert  without mapping CUD actions to stored procedures. The normal pattern is:

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[Product]([Name], ...)
VALUES (@0, ...)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Product]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

So the `INSERT` is followed by a `SELECT`. This is because EF needs to know the identity value that the database assigns to the new `Product` to assign it to the entity object's `Product.ProductId` property and to track the entity. If for some reason you'd decide to do an update immediately after the insert, EF will be able to generate an update statement like `UPDATE ... WHERE Id = @0`.

When the insert is handled by a stored procedure, the sproc should return the new Id value in a way that looks like the regular insert. It expects to receive a one-column result set of which the column is named after the identity column. It should contain one row, the new identity value.

So that's why there is a `SELECT` statement in there, and why EF complains if you remove it. But, you might ask, does EF really need 7 lines of code to get an assigned identity value?

### Why so much code?

Honestly, I have to speculate a bit here, because it isn't documented as far as I can find. But let's look at a minimal working version:

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[Products]([Name])
VALUES (@Name)

SELECT scope_identity() AS ProductId;
```

This does the job. It's even the standard example of many tutorials, including official ones, on mapping CUD actions to stored procedures.

But a database can be stuffed with triggers, constraints, defaults, etc. It's hard to predict their influence on the returned `scope_identity()` under the wide range of circumstances EF may encounter. So EF wants to guarantee that the returned value really belongs to the newly inserted record. And that a record has actually been inserted in the first place. That's why it adds the `SELECT` from the `Product` table, including the `@@ROWCOUNT`.

To implement these safeguards, a minimal version would be:

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[Products]([Name])
VALUES (@Name)

SELECT t0.[ProductId]
FROM [dbo].[Products] AS t0
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[ProductId] = scope_identity()
```

Same as in the regular insert.

That's as far as I can follow EF. It puzzles me a bit that this single `SELECT` apparently is enough for a regular `INSERT` but not for a stored procedure. I can't explain why there are two `SELECT`s in the generated code.

Comment: Gert, thank you for such detailed answer and your insight! It seems to me that there is not enough developers yet that allow Code First to generate their Stored Procedures. Also, glad to see your short version working as well: SELECT scope_identity() AS ProductId;